# Factoring $x^2-6x+9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given the following problem:

> Factor $x^2-6x+9$

The answer would be $(x-3)^2$. But, why is it not $(3-x)^2$? Does it simply not make a difference because in both cases the same answer will be the result because of the square?

Comment: probably a preference in the reference to place variables first.

Comment: Yep.  No difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no difference, as $(3-x)^2=\big[(-1)(x-3)\big]^2=(-1)^2(x-3)^2=(x-3)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $$x-3=-(3-x)$$ and therefore, $$(x-3)^2=\left(-(3-x)\right)^2=(-1)^2(3-x)^2\iff(x-3)^2=(3-x)^2$$

The only way I could see a potential problem is if there is significance in labeling something as $x-3$ as opposed to $3-x$.  Algebraically there is no difference, but there are potential contextual differences.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make any difference. To see why... Suppose that you have a number $x$ and its negative $-x$. Square $-x$. You have:

$(-x)^2=((-1)x)^2=(-1)^2x^2=1*x^2=x^2$.